starting Milvus after building milvus from source code
I built milvus from source on my database cluster.
For that I followed the simple instructions on the milvus repo readme:
# Clone github repository.
$ git clone https://github.com/milvus-io/milvus.git

# Install third-party dependencies.
$ cd milvus/
$ ./scripts/install_deps.sh

# Compile Milvus.
$ make

I also set the path: sudo ldconfig /opt/milvus/internal/core/output/lib/.
Then I run the command: ./scripts/start_cluster.sh
But I get a permission denied response (although I have sudo rights on that that cluster):
Starting rootcoord...
Starting datacoord...
Starting datanode...
./scripts/start_cluster.sh: line 31: /tmp/rootcoord.log: Permission denied
Starting proxy...
./scripts/start_cluster.sh: line 34: /tmp/datacoord.log: Permission denied
Starting querycoord...
Starting querynode...
Starting indexcoord...
./scripts/start_cluster.sh: line 40: /tmp/proxy.log: Permission denied
Starting indexnode...
./scripts/start_cluster.sh: line 43: /tmp/querycoord.log: Permission denied
./scripts/start_cluster.sh: line 46: /tmp/querynode.log: Permission denied

For convenience, here is the source code of the start_cluster.sh file.
Any help with resolving the issue will be appreciated.
